# How to install kivy offline?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to install kivy on a pc that doesn't have an internet connection, so I can't install it using pip. Can someone tell me how to install kivy offline?

Comment: Get the `.whl` file from [here](https://pypi.org/project/Kivy/#files) and run `pip install <filename>.whl`. ***Note: Download .whl file compatible to your system***

Comment: I tried it. First It said (filename).whl doesn't exist in system32. I putted the file there and tried it again. Now it start downloading and then give the error couldn't find version 1.11.1. Maybe I downloaded the wrong file? I'm in a windows 7 64 bit and I downloaded Kivy-1.11.1-cp37m-win_amd64.whl ? Os it the right file. I tried to install it even from python (full path) install and it gives this error: can't find __main__ module in (file path). Any solution?

Comment: @CodeIt please give me a solution

Comment: You may need to download the dependencies as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can download package by `pip download` 
And then install it on offline device.

Find more here [pip download explanation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/)